# php current array position and previous/next

Tags: php, arrays

I have read through many posts regarding previous/next and I am still very much stuck.

I have a page which shows an image and related data. This is obtained from a database. The images are located within the website folder in folders per album. So an image folder may contain 1, 2 or 100 images.

I have a function as follows for this data:-

```
function get_images_album($artist_id) {
    $artist_id = (int)$artist_id;
    $images = array();
    $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`,     
                   `albumname`, `ext`, `timestamp`  FROM `album_images`
                   WHERE `artist_id`=$artist_id AND `member_id`=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
    while ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
        $images[] = array(
            'id' => $images_row['image_album_id'],
            'album' =>  $images_row['artist_id'],
            'albumname' => $images_row['albumname'],
            'ext' => $images_row['ext'],
            'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp']
            );
    }
    return $images;
}
```

The page shows the correct image and data per the url on localhost. Site/album_view.php?artist_id=4&image_album_id=4.

On the html page the code is:-

```
 $images = get_images_album($artist_id);
 if (empty($images)) {
     echo 'There are no Images in this album.';
 }else{
     foreach ($images as $key => $val) {

     }
 }
```

?>

I had understood that if I echo $key and current($val) I would get the array index nos. and image id for the current page. In the case above this would be 0 and 4. However I always get the last index details of the array, which happens to be 13 and 2181 for the particular album.

I know all the data is there as I have echoed the array and all seems ok.

I do not know why.

Going on from what I have I cannot work out how to proceed to get the next and previous settings  Thank you.

Comment: I haven't understood what's your problem actually - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you add `var_dump( $images );` after `$images = get_images_album($artist_id)` and post the results? It would be helpful to see the resulting data set. I'm guessing you're getting those values because it's the last `foreach()` after stepping through the entire result set. Are you trying to obtain each item from the set, or just the first, or.. ?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks your answers.

I am ultimately trying to have a previous/next link to start from the image shown. This could be in array position 1 5 10 or whatever.

Using var_dump($images) gives a result which matches the image shown and will change to reflect whatever image is shown (correctly). So that means if I use a foreach loop it will always show the last element after looping through the list. Hope I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to go about this might be to change your `get_images_album` function slightly:

```
function get_images_album($artist_id) {
  $artist_id = (int)$artist_id;
  $images = array();
  $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT `image_album_id`, `member_id`, `artist_id`,     
                   `albumname`, `ext`, `timestamp`  FROM `album_images`
  WHERE `artist_id`=$artist_id AND `member_id`=".$_SESSION['member_id']);
  While ($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
   // $images[] = array(
   // instead, make your images array a hash and key it on the album_id
    $images[$images_row["image_album_id"]] = array(
      'id' => $images_row['image_album_id'],
      'album' =>  $images_row['artist_id'],
      'albumname' => $images_row['albumname'],
      'ext' => $images_row['ext'],
      'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp']
     );
   }
   return $images;
 }
```

now you can eliminate your `foreach` loop and just get the album you're looking for:

```
 $images = get_images_album($artist_id);
 if (empty($images)) {
 echo 'There are no Images in this album.';
 }else{
  $album_images = $images[$image_album_id];

  // do stuff with the $album_images hash
  var_dump($album_images);

 }
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks your answers.

I am ultimately trying to have a previous/next link to start from the image shown. This could be in array position 1 5 10 or 

Not sure I follow you rkstar. I can get the album ok and an image. But I cannot work out how to get the previous or next image from wherever I am in the array.

I do appreciate your points on the function changes.